# Razor Syntax: Output string array in specific index

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a MVC Class outputting me a list of users grades and the number of them:

```
public class GradeNumModel
{
    public int Grade;
    public int Count;
}
```

Acompanied by an array of subject names:

public class GradeListModel
    {
        public string[] Names = new string[7];

```
    public GradeListModel()
    {
        //Ustawienie pierwszych indeksów na zero pomaga uniknąć problemów przy dodawaniu wartości
        Names[0] = "";
        Names[1] = "Niedostateczny";
        Names[2] = "Dopuszczający";
        Names[3] = "Dostateczny";
        Names[4] = "Dobry";
        Names[5] = "Bardzo Dobry";
        Names[6] = "Celujący";
    }
}
```

Now In my View I have a javascript library called **Chartist** to create charts, to which I would like the such data to be applied.

Here is how I (wanted to) insert my model data into the JS

```
                        var data = {
                            labels: [
                                @foreach (var Gr in Model.AllGradesNum)
                                {
                                    string.Join(Model.GradeList.Names.ElementAt(@Gr.Grade), ", ");
                                }
                            ],
                            series: [
                                @foreach (var Gr in Model.AllGradesNum)
                                {
                                    string.Join(Gr.Count.ToString(), "0, ");
                                }
                            ]
                        };
```

The problem us such configuration outputs no value at all.
Even trying to print the values in the normal div pops up nothing.

The console reports no error as well, checking the sources shows two empty arrays:

```
                var data = {
                    labels: [
                    ],
                    series: [
                    ]
                };
```

What could be the issue here and how can I fix it?

**EDIT: ** 
Outputting the values like this:

```
  @foreach (var Gr in Model.AllGradesNum)
                        {
                            <p>@Gr.Count + @Gr.Grade</p>
                        }
```

Works without issue and displays correct data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issue with your code
1. Your are calculating an expression inside foreach but not printing it out to HTML.
2. Syntax of join is incorrect. Join takes first parameter as separator and second as array, you have swapped that.
Following code might work for you

```
    var data = {
                            labels: [
                                @foreach (var Gr in Model.AllGradesNum)
                                {
                                    string t1 = string.Join(", ",Model.GradeList.Names.ElementAt(@Gr.Grade));
                                    @t1
                                }
                            ],
                            series: [
                                @foreach (var Gr in Model.AllGradesNum)
                                {
                                    string t2 = string.Join("0, ",Gr.Count.ToString());
                                    @t2
                                }
                            ]
                        };
```

Comment: Yay, it works! 
One more small thing tho. How should I output the string to be displayed in double quotes?